# Not able to pull some packages from central repositories for Maven and NPM

Tags: maven, npm, artifactory

We have a setup of Virtual and Remote repositories in JFrog Artifactory. Recently we are seeing issues while pulling packages from Central. e.g The latest version available in Artifactory is 2.3.1: https://xxx.xxx.xx/artifactory/mvn_central/de/codecentric/spring-boot-admin-starter-server/

The newest version is 2.4.1: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.codecentric/spring-boot-admin-starter-server.

Fetching the package from virtual is working which is already in cache but not downloading newer versions from central. We tried deleting the versions from virtual and downloading them again. That works.

We are facing issue with some npm packages also from npm central

Comment: [Central repository](https://search.maven.org/) does not contain npm packages...

Comment: I know, I meant npm packages from NPM central and mvn packages from Maven Central

Comment: Try using the trace capability in order to get more visibility - it should be something like https://xxx.xxx.xx/artifactory/mvn_central/de/codecentric/spring-boot-admin-starter-server/2.4.1/spring-boot-admin-starter-server-2.4.1.jar?trace

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-CacheSettings) on setting up the cache's expiry time. For me, it seems that the "Metadata Retrieval Cache Period" and "Missed Retrieval Cache Period" have higher values, try to set it to lower values or possibly even 0 to test out.